# Powershell Local group and its member collection

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is migrating all my local groups and its member but i do it 1 by 1

1st I get the member and convert it to txt:

```
Get-localgroupmember -group "LD02-SFTPData-105-CSP-Dealer_Upload Reader" | 
Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Backup\6.txt

Get-localgroupmember -group "LD02-SFTPData-112-DealerMovementAutomation Author" | 
Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Backup\7.txt
```

Once collected ill create its group then:

```
New-LocalGroup -Name 'LD02-SFTPData-105-CSP-Dealer_Upload Reader' -Description  ''
```

Then once created:

```
Add-localgroupmember -group "LD02-SFTPData-105-CSP-Dealer_Upload Reader" -member test user
```

is there an easiest way to do this ? or this is the only way?

Comment: The answer depends on what you actually want to do ... probably there's a better way. ;-) You may explain your *end goal* - not the way you think you should go to reach the *end goal*

Comment: You need to describe more.. Now it is unclear whether you want to replicate a group and its members on two different local machines (not in a domain), or if you have the members all in the same AD domain..

Comment: Apology on the late reply our company hit a virus anyway its now ok
going back to my question
my goal is since were migrating
we were trying to get all local group and its member above code is what im using
then will export it to the other server in short inport and export